# Restrict Tkinter LabelFrame from changing proportions in a grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI for reading a PDF file. As soon as I load PDF, the grid expands on x axis.
I have tried setting weights of row and column as 1, but I have no clue what else I am missing.
I want to restrict these 2 LabelFrame from resizing in wrong proportion, even if I resize the window, the proportions should be same.
In short, I want the two LabelFrame to be in equal space!
Does anyone have any idea how to achieve so?

My code

```
import cv2

from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

from tkinter.ttk import Separator
from tkinter import Tk, LabelFrame, Label, Frame, Button
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('1000x600')
        # self.resizable(False, False)
        self.init_frame()

    def open_file(self):
        file_path = askopenfilename(
            title='Select a PDF...',
            filetypes=(('PDF', '*.PDF'),))

        h = self.pdf_frame.winfo_height()
        w = self.pdf_frame.winfo_width()
        print(h, w)

        img = PhotoImage(convert_from_path(file_path, size=(w, h))[0])
        self.pdf_frame.configure(image=img)
        self.pdf_frame.image = img

    def clear_file(self):
        self.init_pdf_frame()

    def init_frame(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news', padx=10, pady=10)

        self.init_pdf_frame()
        self.init_ocr_frame()

    def init_pdf_frame(self):
        image_viewer = LabelFrame(self.frame, text="PDF")
        image_viewer.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        image_viewer.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        image_viewer.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news')

        options = Frame(image_viewer)
        options.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        options.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        options.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky='news')

        open_button = Button(options, text='Open', command=self.open_file)
        open_button.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, sticky='news')

        clear_button = Button(options, text='Clear', command=self.clear_file)
        clear_button.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, sticky='news')

        line = Separator(image_viewer, orient='horizontal')
        line.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        self.pdf_frame = Label(image_viewer, text="PDF result appears here")
        self.pdf_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')

    def init_ocr_frame(self):
        ocr_label = LabelFrame(self.frame, text="OCR")
        ocr_label.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ocr_label.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ocr_label.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='news')

        label = Label(ocr_label, text="PDF result appears here")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='news')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add `uniform=1` to `self.frame.columnconfigure(...)` inside `init_frame()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank You so much!! Finally after stressful hours, you saved me! Also, one more help! The image inside label(pdf image) is not dynamic. I mean to say that if I once load the image from pdf, the image is not resizable if I increase window size. How shall I do this?

Comment: I think you need to call `convert_from_path()` with new `(w, h)` again.

Comment: @acw1668 That's what I am currently doing, I reload the image again. :)